# How to flush all file buffers in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi, buffer

There is `FlushFileBuffers()` API in Windows to flush buffers till hard drive for a *single* file. There is `sync()` API in Linux to flush file buffers for *all* files.

However, is there WinAPI for flushing all files too, i.e. a `sync()` analog?

Comment: Would `fflush(NULL);` work for you as that is specified to "If `stream` is a null pointer, the `fflush` function performs this flushing action on all
streams for which the behavior is defined above"?

Comment: @chux, I think `fflush` flushes only the C/C++ library buffers associated with FILE*. It doesn't flush OS buffers.

Comment: @chux - `fflush` this for flush internal crt streams in current process. nothing common with `FlushFileBuffers` (`IRP_MJ_FLUSH_BUFFERS`)

Comment: One thing that makes good apps is to stop trying Linux things in Windows and vice versa. The philosophy is way different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers

It is possible to flush the entire hard drive.

> To flush all open files on a volume, call FlushFileBuffers with a handle to the volume. The caller must have administrative privileges. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.

Also, the same article states the correct procedure to follow if, for some reason, data must be flushed:  `CreateFile` function with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flags.

> Due to disk caching interactions within the system, the FlushFileBuffers function can be inefficient when used after every write to a disk drive device when many writes are being performed separately. If an application is performing multiple writes to disk and also needs to ensure critical data is written to persistent media, the application should use unbuffered I/O instead of frequently calling FlushFileBuffers. To open a file for unbuffered I/O, call the CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flags. This prevents the file contents from being cached and flushes the metadata to disk with each write. For more information, see CreateFile.

But also check the restrictions of [file buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-buffering) about memory and data alignment.

Comment: Could you show the code how to flush e.g. drive `C:`? I don't understand what's `<i>` in the path for opening a volume...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea you can use a string like "\\\\.\\C:" to open such a handle. However, why do you really want to flush the drive?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - you want to flush the drive to know that the data is really there - even after writing files to disk, bits can still be in caches both within windows and the drive. If you call flush and then have a power failure, the bits have been written. If you don't, no guarantees. Internally operations like ejecting a USB stick also do the flush.

Answer (score 2):

According to [File Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-management-functions) there is no any `sync()` analog from Linux in WinAPI.