# How to flush buffered data after CopyFileEx?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm writing a general-purpose routine that copies a file from one path to another. On Windows, the natural implementation of this function is to use [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfilew) or [`CopyFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw), like this:

```
bool copy_file(const wchar_t* from, const wchar_t* to)
{
    DWORD copy_flags = 0u;
    BOOL cancelled = FALSE;
    BOOL res = CopyFileExW(from, to, NULL, NULL, &cancelled, copy_flags);
    if (!res)
    {
        // Indicate error
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now I need to provide an option to synchronize the copied file with the permanent storage before `copy_file` returns. On POSIX systems this is achieved by calling [`fsync`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html) after the last write operation. In WinAPI, there is [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) function that is intended for this purpose, but it requires a file handle instead of a path.

One possible solution is to open the target file that we just copied and then issue `FlushFileBuffers`, like this:

```
bool copy_file(const wchar_t* from, const wchar_t* to, bool flush)
{
    DWORD copy_flags = 0u;
    BOOL cancelled = FALSE;
    BOOL res = CopyFileExW(from, to, NULL, NULL, &cancelled, copy_flags);
    if (!res)
        return false;

    bool res = true;
    if (flush)
    {
        HANDLE hto = CreateFileW(
            to,
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            NULL);
        if (hto == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return false;

        res = !!FlushFileBuffers(hto);

        CloseHandle(hto)
    }

    return res;
}
```

My main question is if this use of `FlushFileBuffers` is correct. That is, is the `FlushFileBuffers` call guaranteed to cause any buffered data that was copied to `to` by `CopyFileExW` to be flushed to the permanent storage?

If not, can this be fixed by adding `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` to `copy_flags` in the code above? The intention is that `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` would prevent the OS from caching written data, so whatever is not stored on a permanent media must be cached by the storage device, and that would be flushed by `FlushFileBuffers` (as presumably, this call would issue ATA/SCSI/NVME/etc. commands to the device to flush its buffers).

If the above is also not true, is there another way to ensure that the copied data is safely preserved after `copy_file` returns?

A few notes:

I'm aware that `copy_file` could be implemented with a `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` loop, and since those functions work with a file handle, `FlushFileBuffers` would fit nicely into that implementation. However, I would prefer to not do this for various reasons:

Firstly, `CopyFileExW` is documented to copy not only data but also other things, to quote:

> This function preserves extended attributes, OLE structured storage, NTFS file system alternate data streams, security resource attributes, and file attributes.

I come from a POSIX background, and I have no knowledge of some of these things, and I would prefer not to have to learn and implement copying of these bits of information. Additionally, I suspect the list of this information may grow in future Windows versions, and I would like to not have to monitor new Windows features and update my code accordingly.

Secondly, `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` means that the data has to bounce between kernel and userspace, which is bad for performance. I expect that the flushing option of `copy_file` to be used infrequently, so most of the time `copy_file` should perform fast. Therefore, it would be better to avoid copying the data as much as possible.

However, if you think there really is no way around a `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` loop to implement this, please feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Buffering/caching is a function of the OS and driver. Why would you want this?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It is application's responsibility to ensure that any data it has written (or copied) is saved in a permanent storage. This allows to maintain a correct state of data in case of a power or system failure.

Comment: I'd expect `CopyFileExW` to flush before it returns. Are you sure it doesn't? Anyway, opening the target file afterwards and then calling `FlushFileBuffers`  doesn't make much sense. The buffers used to do the copy are gone.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm pretty sure `CopyFileExW` doesn't flush buffers, it is nowhere said it does in the docs. The `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` flag indicates that by default it uses filesystem cache, and that flag alone does not flush device buffers.

Comment: @AndreySemashev On the other hand, `COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE` may cause it to flush "_multiple times during the copy operation_".  I'd be surprised if that indicates that the default is to flush zero times.

Comment: Even if you could use `FlushFileBuffers`, it  will not be clear whether it was called before the crash, so you cannot know whether the copy was performed without errors. It means your goal cannot be achieved.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If it was not called before the crash then `copy_file` didn't return before the crash. Meaning that any caller's logic didn't execute that could rely on the file being reliably copied. I'm fine if the file is not fully copied if the crash happens during `copy_file`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/flushing-system-buffered-i-o-data-to-disk says "If the application does not force the operating system to write the buffer to disk before closing the file, the caching algorithm determines when the buffer is written." which implies opening a new handle after the fact will have no effect on the buffers used by `CopyFile()`

Comment: But see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065902/103167 which recommends flushing the whole volume.

Comment: Use `CopyFile2`. Your callback can flush the file buffers before the handle is closed. Note that hard drives are notorious liars and will report "Yeah, I flushed the data, totally flushed, no problem" even though they didn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt Flushing the whole volume seems like a overkill, and it says it requires administrative privileges. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the hint! It looks like the callback accepted by `CopyFileExW` also receives a file handle, so I could use that as well. The only thing I'm unsure about is whether that callback is called particularly at the point when all data is written and just before the file handle is closed.

Comment: There is a message for "stream finished".

Comment: @AndreySemashev: There's not only the file contents, but master file table, bitmap, and other internal filesystem data structures that must be flushed in order to be able to access the file contents after power interruption.  Presumably `FlushFileBuffers()` takes care of all these even when called on a single handle.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't see a "stream finished" message, there is a "stream changed" one (`CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH`). If you mean `CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED` then that message is presumably used whenever `CopyFileEx` has done copying some portion of data. It is reasonable to assume that that message is used when all data is written, and it looks like that's what happen in practice. IOW, your suggestion works perfectly. If you post an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that's the intention.

Comment: @AndreySemashev You're looking at CopyFileEx. I suggested CopyFile2, which has [COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_STREAM_FINISHED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-copyfile2_message).

Comment: Another trick would be to duplicate the handle in the callback and then flush at each stream switch (and then duplicate the new stream), and one final flush after CopyFile2/CopyFileEx returns.

Answer (score 2):

Raymond has this covered:

As already mentioned in the comments, use the CopyFile2 callback.

### [How can I perform a CopyFile, but also flush the file buffers before the destination handle is closed?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221007-00/?p=107261)

> ... Copy­File­Ex which lets you pass a callback function that is
> called to report on the progress of the file copy, and that callback
> function is our foot in the door. Among other things, the callback
> function is given a reason for the callback, as well as the file
> handles being used for both the source and destination of the copy.
> ...
>
> If you can assume a minimum supported operating system of Windows 8,
> then you can use the newer Copy­File2 function, which calls you back
> when a stream finishes:
>
> ```
> // WARNING! All error checking has been deleted
> // for expository purposes!
>
> HRESULT CopyFileWithFlush(
>     LPCWSTR sourceFileName,
>     LPCWSTR destinationFileName,
>     BOOL failIfExists)
> {
>     COPYFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS params{ sizeof(params) };
>     params.dwCopyFlags = failIfExists ? COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS : 0;
>     params.pProgressRoutine = [](auto message, auto) -> COPYFILE2_MESSAGE_ACTION
>     {
>         if (message->Type == COPYFILE2_CALLBACK_STREAM_FINISHED)
>         {
>             FlushFileBuffers(message->Info.StreamFinished.hDestinationFile);
>         }
>         return COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
>     };
>
>     return CopyFile2(sourceFileName, destinationFileName, &params);
> }
> ```

Note: The linked blog post also contains a solution for `CopyFileEx`.

Comment: Would using the `CopyFileEx` with `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` remove the need to explicitly flush the buffers in the callback?