# Why is CopyFileEx blocking even though the callback reports all bytes have been copied

Tags: windows, winapi, file-copying

I use [CopyFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw) to copy a list of files and keep track of the progress of each individual copy operation through a provided [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nc-winbase-lpprogress_routine) function. At some point, the callback will report that all bytes have been transferred, i.e. the `TotalFileSize` arguments equals `TotalBytesTransferred` argument.

At this point I would expect the call to `CopyFileEx` to return, however for larger files (> 1 Gb) and the destination file being on a convential HDD, it often still takes *several additional* **seconds** on my machine before the function in fact returns.

I'm guessing this has to do with flushing disk caches or whatever else is going on behind the scenes in the system.

My problem with this is that it makes for a very unsatisfying user experience, i.e. have a progress bar sitting at 100% and then have seemingly nothing happen for 10 seconds or more before the next file is being copied. Is there any way I can work around this?

Specifying the `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` flag doesn't seem to help the problem.

Comment: Have you tried CopyFile2? It's more recent (Windows 8) and more capable (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620715/how-to-flush-buffered-data-after-copyfileex)

Comment: If I copy large files with the Windows File Explorer, the green progress chart it displays shows a similar behavior (the progress is stuck for a couple of seconds at the very end, before the progress dialog closes itself), so I suspect that even Microsoft themselves have the same issue you are experiencing here.

Comment: @SimonMourier The systems I'm targetting are still on Windows 7, so sadly it's not an option.

Comment: need look under debugger what is happens. you have several seconds to suspend process, and than look call stack, where is api "wait" at the end

Comment: Temporarily disable security software and try again.

Comment: I would have the callback display a UI message indicating the file is being finalized when it reaches 100%, and then hide that message when the next file begins and when `CopyFileEx()` exits.

Comment: @HansPassant There is no security software running on the system. Windows defender is disabled too.

Comment: I'm sorry to say Windows7 is out of support. It seems there is something to be copied like metadata and is reasonable.

Comment: Copying "something like metadata" taking 10 seconds is reasonable?  Sorry but I disagree.

Comment: You can open an incident about the behavior of `CopyFileEx()` via 'Contact us' tab at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/ so that our engineer can work with you closely. In-addition, if the support engineer determines that the issue is the result of a bug the service request will be a no-charge case and you won't be charged.